# Why does Microsoft define a type CHAR as char and a macro CONST as const?

Tags: c, windows, types, macros

As a C beginner, looking through [MSDN's Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), I see there are a lot of types that are defined that seem redundant.

For example using `typedef`:

- CHAR -- `typedef char CHAR;`
- FLOAT -- `typedef float FLOAT;`

also as object macros:

- CONST -- `#define CONST const`

As I understand it `typedef` and `#define` are often used to either clarify programmer intention:

```
#define BOOL int
```

and/or to shorten type declarations (couldn't think of a good example):

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

However I don't understand how there can be any benefit simply replacing char with CHAR.

So why does Microsoft define these types?

Comment: because... microsotft

Comment: kidding aside I suspect there must be historical reasons

Comment: @bolov yup it seems so, there are some good answers at the duplicate above.

Comment: It is the fundamental way that Microsoft isolates the winapi from the C compiler implementation.  Programs written 30 years ago that used these typedefs, targeting a 16-bit 8086 processor, still compile and run today on a 64-bit Haswell processor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, unsubstantiated by any research.

The fundamental types in the language have all lower case types. It's possible that the standard will start using `byte` as a type in the future but it is unlikely to use `BYTE` as a type. Microsoft chose to create several types, using `typedef` and `#define`, that made sense to them and programming for their platform easier for some. They also made sure that their types don't conflict with what the standard might use in the future.

If you use `BYTE` as a type, wouldn't you rather use `CHAR` as a type instead of `char`?

Comment: That's an interesting theory, I think there might be some truth to it. There's actually some great answers over at the duplicate.